# Why android studio crashes automatically?

Tags: android, android-studio, ide, android-sdk-tools

My studio's current version is 0.9.9 (recently updated), now here is the history:

There was some problems when I shifted eclipse to studio. The last problem happened when I updated it. My app became full of error. One of them was `cannot resolve Symbol ActionbarActivity`. And so many others. I spend a day behind it and gave up. I recreated my app from first to last with the same resources, then it became totally good to go. Three days later(today) again another problem raised. I turned on my laptop, opened Android studio and it says `Rendering problem No Android SDK found. Please configure an Android SDK.` But last night it was running fine. Now there is no design window.

I am wondering that why the errors come automatically. I don't do anythings in the settings stuff of the studio. I just develop my app. I just write code and make my app. So whats wrong with the studio. It crashes without any reason and I have to waste the half of the time. Is this a kind of jokes? It too much irritating. Updating latest version is not the reason. The problem is occurring from whenever I downloaded the Android Studio and shifted from Eclipse to it. With 2 or 3 days intervals it comes with new problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try fresh Installation or, As it happens because of some internal Intellij's libraries problem.